# Unable to change value of string from @property

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a variable which multiple methods need to access and change.

I have declared it as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *curDate;
```

I then synthesise it in the code as well.

However, when trying to change it's value like so:

```
curDate = "02-07-2012";
```

the app crashes.

Why is this? How should I change this value?

Comment: @H2CO3 Actually it just dumped a stack trace. Couldn't understand it.

Comment: Didn't the compiler show a warning about "Incompatible pointer types"? And if you happen to use Xcode: clicking on the yellow warning triangle opens a pop-up with the option *Fix it: Insert "@"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `@` symbol when using the `NSString` literal syntax.

Like this:

`curDate = @"02-07-2012";`

Read all about the usage of the `@` symbol in Objective-C [here](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/).

Answer (score 0):

```
curDate = @"02-07-2012";
```

You'v made literal error